# How do I fix this NoSuchMethodError inFlutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am following along with an online course yet my code throws an error where the instructor's code doesn't. Yes, I've scanned over it to make sure they are identical.
Maybe there is some small detail I've missed. At any rate, can someone please help me fix this error so I can move on?
Here is the get method:

```
  List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues {
    return List.generate(7, (index) {
      final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
        Duration(days: index),
      );
  var totalSum = 0.0;

  for (int i; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
    if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
        recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
        recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
      totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
    }
  }

  return {
    'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay).substring(0, 1),
    'amount': totalSum,
  };
});
```

}

And here is the implementation of it in Flutter:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Row(
        children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {

        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the error message:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Chart(dirty):
The method '<' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: <(0)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      Chart.groupedTransactionValues.<anonymous closure> 
package:expense/widgets/chart.dart:19
#2      new List.generate  (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:78:28)
#3      Chart.groupedTransactionValues 
package:expense/widgets/chart.dart:13
#4      Chart.build 
package:expense/widgets/chart.dart:45
#5      StatelessElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4620
#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4546
#7      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4262
#8      ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4525
#9      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4520
#10     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3490
#11     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5991
...     Normal element mounting (109 frames)
#120    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3490
#121    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5991
...     Normal element mounting (210 frames)
#331    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3490
#332    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5991
...     Normal element mounting (273 frames)
#605    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3490
#606    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3258
#607    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1174
#608    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1145
#609    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1087
#610    BuildOwner.buildScope 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2620
#611    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1086
#612    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:927
#613    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:908
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
```

This is the part causing the Error, since it is stated: "The method '<' was called on null." You have to initalise your int i = 0, so the code should look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
```

Comment: That's it! Appreciate you!